# How to trigger PrimeNG Accordion Click programmatically in Angular 2.0?

Tags: angular, accordion, primeng

I have an accordion as shown below.

When the link is clicked, I'd need to trigger the click event of all p-accordianTab elements.

How is it possible?

```
<a (click)="openCloseAll()" >{{openCloseAllText}} all</a>
                <p-accordion [multiple]="true">
                    <div class="row" *ngFor="let category of result.Categories">                        

                            <p-accordionTab #accordianTab header="{{category.Name}}">

                            </p-accordionTab>                       

                    </div>
                </p-accordion>
```

I tried adding this "#accordionTab" to the  element and accessing it from TypeScript but doesn't work:

```
@ViewChild('accordionTab') accordionTab: ElementRef;
 openCloseAllText: string = "Open";
 openCloseAll() {
        // get all accordions and click them
        this.openCloseAllText = this.openCloseAllText === "Open" ? "Close" : "Open";
        this.accordionTab.nativeElement.click();
    }

TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the accordion a [reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!%23ref-vars) and using a `ViewChild`?

Comment: Yes. Odd answer, wasn't it very clear in the question that I did try that?

Comment: Not an answer, a comment. And one that came before you edited that information into the question.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just use the tabs-property of the accordion itself?

```
<p-accordion #accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header Content">
         Body Content
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>

@ViewChild('accordion') accordion: Accordion;

closeAllAccordionTabs() {
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.accordion.tabs)){
        for(let tab of this.accordion.tabs) {
            if(tab.selected) tab.selected = false;
        }
    }
}

openAllAccordionTabs() {
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.accordion.tabs)){
        for(let tab of this.accordion.tabs) {
            if(!tab.selected) tab.selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got errors when I have used your approach "Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry, it's solved now. I forgot to add #accordion in p-accordion tag

Comment: How to trigger an specific tab of the accordian. I'm usinh Primeng 11 LTs please help.

Answer (score 3):

updated [Martin Kronstad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501390/4561506) for es6 w/ arrow functions:

```
  closeAllAccordionTabs() {
    if (this.accordion && this.accordion.tabs) {
      this.accordion.tabs.forEach(tab => tab.selected = false);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working using the same approach as you but moving the template variable to an element inside a custom p-header, instead of on the p-accordion-Tab.

```
<p-accordionTab>
    <p-header>
        <span #header>
            Header Content
        </span>
    </p-header>
    Body Content
</p-accordionTab>
```

Their doc page has info on the bottom about using custom header content: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate method that doesn't require @ViewChild. Use this if your accordion is in an *ngIf and is only added to the DOM on certain conditions(In this case the @ViewChild is undefined and can't be set).

Use the activeIndex property:

`<p-accordion [activeIndex]="openAccordion">`

Put this variable in the component:

`openAccordion = -1;`

When you want to open the accordion set this.openAccordion to the index of the accordion tab you want to open. e.g.

`this.openAccordion = 0;`

or in a unit test as I'm using it:

`fixture.componentInstance.openAccordion = 0;`

Comment: One thing I noticed with this approach is things got real weird until I used [(activeIndex)]. I was expanding/collapsing individual tabs and all at once, so without the 2 way binding things got out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in HTML

```
<p-accordion (onOpen)='onTabOpen($event)'>
<p-accordionTab *ngFor='let chart of chartList' header='{{chart.chartName}}'>
<div *ngFor='let content of chartContentList'>{{content.referenceName}}</div>
</p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

and in Typescript, write the onTabOpen event handler

```
chartList: ChartModel[]=[];
chartContentList: ChartContentModel[]=[];

onTabOpen(e){
const index=e.index
const contentList=this.chartList.filter(x=>x.id==index);
this.service.getChartContent(contentList[0].chartName).subscribe((res)=>{
if(res){
this.chartContentList=res;
}
});
}
```

so, when you click on any header tab it passes the index to OnTabOpen handler then it gets the content to load under the tab and binds its dynamically.

View Model :

```
public interface ChartModel{
id?:number;
chartName?:string;
}

public interface ChartContentModel{
referenceName?:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `selected` attribute of the p-accordion:

```html
<a (click)="openCloseAll()" >{{openCloseAllText}} all</a>
<p-accordion [multiple]="true" [seleted]="accordionTrigger">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let category of result.Categories">                        
        <p-accordionTab #accordianTab header="{{category.Name}}">
        </p-accordionTab>                       
    </div>
</p-accordion>
```

```js
accordionTrigger: boolean = false;    // false is closed and true is opened

changeAccordion() {
    this.accordionTrigger = !this.accordionTrigger;
}
```

If you have many accordions, you can do a array of boolean and set an id to each accordion too.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a "Collapse All" and "Expand All" feature for the p-accordion in multiple mode, and none of the solutions here worked, so here's mine (Angular 16.2.8, primeng 16.0.2)

In my template :

```html
<p-accordion #accordion [multiple]="true" [activeIndex]="activeIndexes">
<!-- [...] -->
</p-accordion>
```

In my component :

```js
  @ViewChild('accordion') accordion: Accordion;
  public activeIndexes: number[] = [];

  public collapseAll() {
    this.activeIndexes = [];
    if (this.accordion) 
      this.accordion.updateSelectionState();
  }

  public expandAll() {
    this.activeIndexes = this.rapportsJournees.map((_, index) => index);
    if (this.accordion) 
      this.accordion.updateSelectionState();
  }
```

---

Without the call to `this.accordion.updateSelectionState()` i had to click twice, so i checked the [p-accordion source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/9a9599b9041f71cd74824d81bb540e4af135bd73/src/app/components/accordion/accordion.ts#L394)