# Is it possible to close all the opened PrimeNg accordion tab on a button click in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a menu with PrimeNg accordion:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

and I want to close that accordion on a button click. Is it possible in Angular 2?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901922/how-to-trigger-primeng-accordion-click-programmatically-in-angular-2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger PrimeNG Accordion Click programmatically in Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901922/how-to-trigger-primeng-accordion-click-programmatically-in-angular-2-0)

Comment: @GianlucaParis this post seems to have a broader scope. Besides it's a possible solution, for the simple case of closing the accordion on a button click, there's an easier way of doing it, posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's an easy way to do it:

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-chevron-up" (click)="closeAccordion()"></button>

<p-accordion [activeIndex]="index">
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
    Content 1
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
    Content 2
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
    Content 3
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

TS code:

```
  index: number = null;
  lastIndex = -1;

  closeAccordion() {
    this.index = this.lastIndex--;
  }
```

Comment: tried but not working